# Force Autologon after boot menu choice without restart

Tags: windows-7, autologon

I’m new to this great forum.

Ok, I created a boot menu for Windows 7 with 2 options: Normal start and Auto start.
When a user selects Normal then Windows starts normally and goes to Ctrl+Alt+Del…
And when a user selects Auto then I want the pc to logon automatically en goes to IE-kiosk mode.
I cannot get Autologon working without a reboot. Via a GPO with vbs-start-script which checks the users choice and configure the registry etc for Autologon. I got Autologon works well however only if I force the pc to reboot after choosing the Autologon menu option. 
My question is: can I force the pc to Autologon directly after the user chooses for Auto (Autologon)?

TIA for any advice/ alternatives!

Comment: I think you need to provide more details on how your boot menu entries are different from each other.

Comment: The boot menu entries are no different. Only the display name is different. Both menu -items uses the same drive and OS> I create the menu entries using bcedit. The choice of the user is checked during startup by a GPO script to triggers Autologon if the user wants to autologon toward IE-Kiosk mode.

Comment: You can't do it like that because when you set the registry via computer-level GPO it won't take effect until the next reboot. The first time it's applied, it's _just_ applied not executed, because by the time it applies the changes to those settings, the existing settings have already been read and used.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Is ther any other way to achieve that goal?